# Dumping a data structure like pickle in python

Tags: ocaml, object-serialization, data-dump

Could you please recommend library where I could dump a runtime data structure such as a `Map` or `Set` which behaves like the `pickle` library that does the object serialization in Python?

Comment: [Yojson](https://github.com/ocaml-community/yojson) seems quite popular for this sort of task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For personal projects, you can use the [Marshal](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Marshal.html) module of the standard library which is essentially the OCaml version of `pickle`.

For instance, if I have a set

```
module Int_set = Set.Make(Int)
let set = Int_set.of_list [1;2;3;4]
```

that I want to seralize to a file named

```
let set_file = "set_file"
```

I can do it with

```
let () =
  Out_channel.with_open_bin set_file (fun chan ->
      Marshal.to_channel chan set []
  )
```

and I can read back this file with

```
let set: Int_set.t = In_channel.with_open_bin set_file  Marshal.from_channel
```

and check that everything is fine with

```
let () =
  let pp_sep ppf () = Format.fprintf ppf ",@ " in
  Format.printf "@[set={%a}@]@."
    Format.(pp_print_seq ~pp_sep pp_print_int) (Int_set.to_seq set)
```

However, like Python's pickle, the `Marshal` module is not safe: you should only unmarshal data from files that you trust as much as your executable.
Thus for non-personal project, it might be better to consider other serialization formats.

(Another limitation is that `Marshal` cannot serialize reliably data structures that contain functions (it is not impossible but it is better to avoid Marshall `Closures` flag).)